# show data like a display in python

Tags: python, spyder

i have a litle program to read data from an arduino attached to an accelerometer. I'm getting the data, process them and finally i'm printing all data in a row in the IPTerminal. I need to see the data as a display in several  separated windows and just the last number of each column. Like a display of a device.

I'm getting ths:

```
16012| 15764| 384| 172| 52| -136| -376| -424| 12| -30| -195| -232
16052| 15776| 380| 136| 40| -240| -394| -428| 4| -33| -179| -246
16096| 15736| 396| 136| 68| -168| -381| -428| 16| -28| -185| -243
16048| 15760| 380| 208| 40| -184| -380| -421| 11| -38| -187| -242
16016| 15748| 372| 156| 20| -152| -383| -424| 8| -26| -181| -247
15988| 15764| 376| 140| 52| -164| -388| -429| 16| -35| -197| -230
16064| 15740| 452| 188| 68| -140| -385| -423| 9| -36| -186| -231
16060| 15780| 384| 188| 64| -192| -377| -429| 11| -36| -186| -235
16056| 15776| 364| 156| 68| -116| -394| -434| 19| -24| -185| -232
16056| 15764| 352| 172| 28| -200| -378| -419| 7| -27| -189| -231
16048| 15724| 372| 112| 40| -172| -388| -434| 10| -36| -181| -243
16060| 15760| 340| 136| 52| -164| -379| -428| -2| -30| -197| -243
```

i can't even show the data without a \nl

I'm looking for several little windows like this:

[image: multimeter display]

Thanks.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you're asking. Do you have a physical LED panel hooked up to your Ardiuino you want to render content to? If not, what kind of interface are you trying to render onto? Is it hardware physically attached to the Arduino, or are you trying to build a display interface that sits on the other end of a serial line (in which case the fact that there's an Arduino involved anywhere becomes superfluous to the question)? Or is it a web interface that presents your data you're trying to build? So many unanswered questions...

Comment: So this is a Spyder question?  You want to create displays in windows managed by that environment?  If so have you written any display code in that environment, and just have a specific issue, or are you asking someone to write all the display logic for you? - This isn't a site for free programming.  You need to ask something more specific if you aren't just asking to have something written for you.

Comment: No i have not a LED panel, i want a window to display my data as if it were a panel. I have to proces the data that is why im using python (spider).

Comment: No i'm looking for an advise like "use this_magic_function(data) and it will pop a window displaying your data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the carriage return `\r`, which resets the cursor in the terminal to the start of the current line. For example.

```py
import sys
import time
# Print first line
print('this will disappear', end='')
sys.stdout.flush()

time.sleep(1)

# Replace it
print('\rand be replaced by this', end='')
```